# VBA Output new collection to single cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need to get unique values from a range, in a specific cell.
A1=x, A2=y, A3=z, A4=x
I want to get B1=x,y,z
My solution is:
concatenate A1,A2,A3,A4, in B2.
split B2.
make new collection from splitted B2.
output collection elements into C1, C2, ..Ci
concatenate C1, C2,..Ci into B1

Is possible to avoid to output collection into C1,C2 ? but output directly into B1 through some variable ?

```
   '''''''  
concatenation part    
''''''''
    Dim ary As Variant
    Dim Arr As New Collection, a
    Dim i As Long
    ary = split(Range("b2"), ",")

    For Each a In ary
    Arr.Add a, a
    Next

    For i = 1 To Arr.count
    Cells(1, i+2) = Arr(i) ' output collection in some cells
    Next
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''
concatenation part
'''''''''''
```

Thank you.

Comment: IMO your question / problem description is hard to follow. I'd suggest adding a cropped screenshot or two.

Comment: in the array, split again, spit(a,"=")

Comment: For unique values, would you not want to look at: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=160873 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a late binding "on the fly" `Dictionary` object:

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In Range("A1:A4") '<--| change "A1:A4" to whatever range you need
            .Item(cell.Value) = .Item(cell.Value) + 1
        Next cell
        Range("B1").Value = Join(.keys, ",")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. your solution is the clearest and simple, even i need to quit the initial concatenation

Comment: Also, if you selected the rows with your mouse & cursor, you could replace the argument ("A1:A4") with Selection.Address:          
For Each cell In Range(Selection.Address)

Answer (score 0):

in the array, `split` again, `spit(a,"=")` adding index 1 to another array, not a collection, then use `JOIN` to put it back together

```
x=0
redim arrOutput(ubound(ary))
For Each a In ary
    arrOutput(x)= split(a,"=")(1)
    x=x+1
Next

range("b1")=join(arrOutput,",")
```

or just split by = and take odd numbers from the resulting array maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hold something unique - always think about dictionary, cause of `Exists` method. Here's a small example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim NonUniqueValues As Variant
    Dim UniqueValues As Object
    Dim i As Long

    'gather source array
    NonUniqueValues = Union([A1], [A2], [A3], [A4]).Value2

    'set dict
    Set UniqueValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'loop over array
    For i = LBound(NonUniqueValues, 1) To UBound(NonUniqueValues, 1)
        If Not UniqueValues.Exists(NonUniqueValues(i, 1)) Then _
                Call UniqueValues.Add(Key:=NonUniqueValues(i, 1), Item:=NonUniqueValues(i, 1))
    Next

    'output
    [B1] = Join(UniqueValues.Keys, ",")

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Public Function KonKat(rng As Range) As String
    Dim c As Collection, r As Range, i As Long

    Set c = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each r In rng
            c.Add r.Value, CStr(r.Value)
        Next r
    On Error GoTo 0

    For i = 1 To c.Count
        KonKat = KonKat & "," & c.Item(i)
    Next i
        KonKat = Mid(KonKat, 2)
End Function
```

[image]